# Print time dynamically based on server time zone

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I've read many posts about the question I posted here but I'm encountering a strange issue.

I've set my PHP server timezone to `"Asia/Bangkok"` (just an example) using  `date.timezone` directive in `php.ini` file which works quite fine.

The server returns correct time based on set time zone when I simply print the time as

```
<?php echo date("F j, Y, g:i A"); ?>
```

But when I want to print a series of time dynamically, inputted into `mysql` database during user entry like,

```
<?php echo date("F j, Y g:i A", strtotime($row_entries['input_time']));?>
```

The server returns the `system` time based on the timezone set by host which is `Europe/Dublin` (just an example).

I even tried to print the time without `strtotime` function like,

```
 <?php echo date("F j, Y g:i A",($row_entries['post_time']));?>
```

That returns abnormal/invalid date.

What's going wrong here and how could I print time dynamically based on server time zone I set in `php.ini`?

Comment: what is the datatype of field in database where you are trying to store data? try simple varchar to avoid internal transformations.

Comment: @OZ_  i'm using `timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. i hesitate to use `varchar` for storing time. thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this row

```
$row_entries['post_time']
```

uses MYSQL default time zone which is different

so please could you post SQL that insert data in this column ?

Comment: i've edited my question. we can think about a corrective measure based on `$row_entries['input_time']`. thanks,

Comment: i can't catch what you want to say !  
but when user input post you should consider setting time row as  
$row_entries['input_time'] = date("F j, Y g:i A");  
or if it's a time then  
$row_entries['input_time'] = time ();  
don't use mysql now() function !

Comment: you are correct `$row_entries['post_time']` or `$row_entries['input_time']` use MYSQL default time zone `(system time)`. how can i edit the time zone in `mysql` on shared unix server? thanks,

Comment: You can use SET time_zone = 'Asia/Bangkok';

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your MySQL is not configured to the correct timezone. Here is a link to configure: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: i'm on a shared unix server. which variable should i edit in this case available in `mysql` `information_schema` `tables`? thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> i'm using timestamp

1) use int to store digit or varchar for text or datetime to store date and time.
2) read about default behavior of this datatype - value will be updated when ANY other field in the record will be updated. This datatype is only should be used for logging purposes.

Comment: i know and realize what you say but i don't want bypass the appropriate `datatype` assigned for the respective fields. thanks,

Comment: updated. anyway, timestamp is dangerous type and should be use only when you understand that value will be updated each time you touch the record.

Comment: of course `timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` shall update the value every time i update the data. thanks,

Comment: then before storing it, convert time value into UTC. You can use DateTime functions for that.